# Release/Build/Branching Management with Git (Version Control)

Tags: android, git, version-control

I've ran into a common problem that I don't know how to properly solve. I do have a `dev branch` in which I've merging all of the branches (`feature/hotfix`) that are done, but suddenly, they want to release a specific feature or just to release the hotfixes only. How can I properly/orgnanize merge `dev` to `master` without including the `feature/hotfix` that they don't want if I've already merge it to the `dev`?

**One solution** that I've been thinking of is branching out from `dev` then exclude all the things they don't want, then release it on production, but I will not merge it to `master`. Then after they've accepted all of the `features` or `hotfixes` on the `dev`, that's only the time I will merge to `master`, and I will just simply ignore/delete the branch out from `dev` (which is the branch that have excluded the feature they don't want) that I've made.

**Second Solution** that I've been thinking is releasing an apk per feature or hotfix, but I don't think the testers will like to hold many apks on their phone with specific feature each. But with that, I can surely merge feature or hotfix that is accepted to `dev` because they mark it to be included on the next release.

Any other solutions or suggestions on how I manage branching?

Comment: normally you should not be merging hotfix in dev but in master: they are hotfixes that means things that you want to merge quickly right?

Comment: for a hotfix you should normally create a build to be tested in isolation, I mean without any other change. For features it depends on your QA I worked in companies where the testers use to test only before the release that means with many new features in a single build and companies where QA tests one feature at a time

Comment: @kingston Oh, I didn't think of that, well because they must test it first that's why I always merge it first to dev, then to testing, then to master. Maybe hotfix can be go straight to master after they've tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 is more reasonable.

Since the `dev` branch already contains merged features and hotfixes, you should exclude some features/hotfixes which are not required for release from `dev` branch (or branch created from `dev`).

But one thing for reminder, since you treat the branch from `dev` as production branch (instead of `master` branch), please make sure changes from `master` branch are included in the branch from `dev`.

Besides, `.apk` files are output files from your source code, it’s unnecessary to manage the `.apk` files in your git repo.

And you can find more files which need to be ignored in this [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) file.

Comment: So solution 1 is a good to go? thanks for the reminder. Yes, I don't include apks on the repo, I'm just thinking of building multiple apk for them to test with each apk having specific feature.

Comment: Yes, solution 1 is ok. And for ignoring the apk files, you can make no changes since they haven't added in your git repo :)